# Windows reports Panda Free Antivirus' firewall is off

Tags: windows, firewall, anti-virus

My Windows 10 OS is reporting a warning on Windows Defender Security Center:

[image: Windows Defender Security Center showing warning: Actions needed in Panda Firewall]

However, my Panda Free Antivirus doesn't have a firewall and I don't see any warnings on Panda frontend.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Panda 18.0 problem with a Windows Update. Panda 18.4 fixes it: http://acs.pandasoftware.com/Panda/FREEAV/190612/FREEAV.exe